# Does the server need to be a pointer

Tags: go

According to [The http#Server.ListenAndServe documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.ListenAndServe)

```
func (*Server) ListenAndServe
```

takes server as a pointer

And according to [https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/] it seems that the server should be created as pointer

```
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:              ":8080",
    Handler:           nil,
    TLSConfig:         nil,
    .....
}
```

But, this works perfectly fine. What am I missing here?

```
    server := http.Server{
    Addr:              ":8080",
    Handler:           nil,
    ......
}

if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err!=nil{
    log.Fatal("oh Dear!")
}
```

Comment: Where does the documentation say that? Can you quote the specific claim? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: I was specifically going of  https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=88291:88332#L2803
 and
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/
turns out i was wrong in my assumption\understanding

Comment: The reason I downvoted is because your question doesn't make sense, as you yourself admitted. You mis-read the documentation.

Comment: Argue the semantics all you like. You asked why I down-voted, and I explained. I stand by that reason. Your question says "The documentation says X", but the documentation doesn't say X. I call that misreading. Call it what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "[Go Syntax of calling a function with pointer receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9958152/6309)", and
the spec: "[Method Set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)"

> The method set of the corresponding pointer type `*T` is the set of all methods with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).

So [`func (*Server) ListenAndServe`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.ListenAndServe) works both for `Server` and `*Server`.

Answer (score 2):

Both examples use the address of an `http.Server`.  The first example explicitly takes the address of an `http.Server`.

In the second example, the call  `server.ListenAndServe()` is shorthand for `(&server).ListenAndServe()`.

Here's the [relevant text from the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) on the shorthand:

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m()

The short handle is applied because  variable `server` is [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) and `&server`'s [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) contains `ListenAndServe()`.

Answer (score 1):

The method is defined with a pointer receiver, meaning it must be called on an addressable receiver. So, for instance:

```
func f() http.Server {...}

f().ListenAndServe()
```

would not work.

When you call:

```
server.ListenAndServe()
```

the method receives the address of `server` instead of a copy of it.